# Using local cache along with Doctrine ORM

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, silex

I was working with Silex and Doctrine ORM. To make my database queries faster, I wanted to have a caching of some sort.

I looked at PhpFastCache - which provides a good caching framework - but does not really integrate with Doctrine. The best part about this is that I can have a local cache independent of any external service - like memcached. Since I have a small site which is hosted on shared host, I cannot spend money on having a service on cloud.

I also looked at existing cache providers for Doctrine ORM and all of them use external cache service.

The last thing I know I would have to do is write a provider myself using the PhpFastCache, but just wanted to make sure that there is no alternative online that I can use. I have tried my best by searching online all day today, but I just wanted to make sure.

Just to add: I have looked at APC and Memcache, but I have my site on shared hosting, and I would need a dedicated hosting for installing the PECL modules for APC/Memcache :(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quickly wrote a provider for PhpFastCache. I have added the gist here:

https://gist.github.com/thephoenics/ee7de9f95bfdf5f6c24f

Answer (score 4):

Doctrine includes quite a few cache drivers that do not seem to be documented. There is not one for PhpFastCache, but there are two that cache **directly to the filesystem**. Check out [FilesystemCache](https://github.com/doctrine/cache/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/FilesystemCache.php) and [PhpFileCache](https://github.com/doctrine/cache/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/PhpFileCache.php). You can see the [full list](https://github.com/doctrine/cache/tree/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache) in the repository.

If I had to guess, I'd say that **FilesystemCache** is what you want. It stores serialized data in a plain file. PhpFileCache stores it as a PHP file, and then uses `include` to read it later. That means it has to be parsed by PHP on read, which is probably slower unless you use a PHP bytecode cache like APC.

Neither solution will be as fast as something like Memcache since they both read from the filesystem instead of memory, but they should provide an optimization for slow database queries that are run often.

**Edit**: As Kiran Madipally pointed out, it should be easy create your own PhpFastCache  driver by extending [CacheProvider](https://github.com/doctrine/cache/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/Common/Cache/CacheProvider.php).

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good option to start with. I am also thinking I can extend the Cache Provider in the fashion that the FileSystemCache provider was created - using PhpFastCache. Will spend some time on that and if I can do it easily - I'll have a Cache Provider with PhpFastCache :).

Comment: PhpFileCache will likely smoke memcached and apc in performance, IF you enable the opcache. It's an unsung cache. Mostly suitable for stuff that doesn't change much, as it's not very dynamic.